# How to create a visual tree from XML Schema

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Can someone guide me the right direction I'm trying to create a visual tree from xml schema. lets say I'm given

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="shiporder">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="shipto">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

and I would have to make following. [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPcUK.png)

[image]

The approach I took was to just look at the xs:element name atribute and get the value of it. I was able to get the attribute of the first  xs:element which is 'shiporder'.

```
  function xmlFunc(xml){
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml")
  var x = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
  for(var i=0; i < x.length; i++){
   if( x[i].nodeValue == undefined || x[i].nodeValue == null ){
    console.log(x[i].getAttribute("name"));
    console.log(x[i].getAttributeNode("name").nodeValue);
    }
    else {
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Then I tried to use the .find() method from jquery. to find the the rest of the xs:elements:

```
  console.log($(xmlDoc).find('xs:element');
```

How can I make it print the attribute name for each xs:element?. Can someone direct me the right way?

Comment: your `selector` is now a collection of **all** (!) `'xs:element[name="name"]'` and than you're trying to `.find` ***all (!!!)** those* inside *every* `"xs:element"`...

Comment: I suggest using `xmlDoc.evaluate()` with an XPath expression. It's a bit unclear exactly what the end goal is, however.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thank you! I fixed it